# Spring Boot/Security/Apache CXF SOAP service access restriction

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, cxf

I have created Apache CXF SOAP webservice in Spring Boot as per below config:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean wsDispatcherServlet() {
 return new ServletRegistrationBean(new CXFServlet(), "/service/*");
}

@Bean
public Endpoint pegaEndpoint() {
 EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(springBus, "/service/");
 endpoint.publish("ws");
 return endpoint;
}
```

Now I want to use httpBasic authentication to call a web service, but at the same time I want the WSDL to be publicly accessible.
Is that possible to configure with Spring Security?
I have below code in Java Configuration class for security, but it doesnt really work - 
the basic authentication is enforced on both web service calls and wsdl accessed by `http://localhost:8080/service/ws?WSDL`

Can Spring Security differentiate based on the URL param?
Or can I set a WSDL location to be different that the URL used to call the web service?

```
@Autowired
private void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
 auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
}

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().                                                                                  
        antMatchers("/service/**").hasRole("USER").and().httpBasic().and().
        csrf().disable();
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/service/ws?wsdl");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing below. Apparently ant matchers dont recognize any URL parameters so I used regex one:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().regexMatchers("/service/ws\\?WSDL");
}
```

Comment: can you please look at my question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72578781/soap-web-service-is-sending-response-even-when-the-request-does-not-have-okta-to

Answer (score 0):

Permit all on the wsdl should do it -

```
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/service/ws?wsdl").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/service/**").hasRole("USER").and().httpBasic().and().
        csrf().disable();
```